# Python http request hangs endlessly

Tags: python, timeout, python-requests

I am having an issue getting a response from a server in a production environment.  The problem only occurs when in the production environment.  When in an interactive shell I make the request as follows.

```
r = requests.get('https://cdp.dhs.gov/femasid_test_api')
```

But the request just hangs there.  If I set the timeout variable.

```
r = requests.get('https://cdp.dhs.gov/femasid_test_api', timeout=10)
```

Then there is an exception raised.

```
SSLError: _ssl.c:489: The handshake operation timed out
```

I can run this request without any problems from a vagrant instance of the same project and get an appropriate response.  I have also been able to make requests to a few other endpoints from the production machine. ie:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
```

Any help would be appreciated or suggestions on how to further diagnose the issue.  If you need to know anything further about the setup that we are running let me know.

Comment: I tested your first and second request ('https://cdp.dhs.gov/femasid_test_api') it returns 200, but you should be getting an `u'invalid endpoint /femasid_test_api'` message

Comment: Is there something in your environment that is preventing the use of TLS 1.0?

Comment: Here is the ssl labs test results from the sending environment.     https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=moi.ndptc.manoa.hawaii.edu

Comment: Weird and possibly unrelated, but this happens to me right now with pypi.org. `requests.get("https://pypi.org/pypi/rope/json")` hangs, `curl https://pypi.org/pypi/rope/json` works. Also, everything runs smoothly in Docker, still can't figure it out.